# Specifying image, text and title on facebook share without meta og tags

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm trying to build in a facebook share button on a news section of a site. I would like to specify which picture, title and text to use for the share.

Due to limitations in the cms that the website uses i can't add the open graph meta in the header of the page. I've tried updating the og meta with javascript and just adding them in the body instead to no success.

Is there any other way to specify image, title and text in facebook share using just xslt or client side tech like javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, you can't do this with share buttons.  However, you can get similar functionality out of [stream.publish](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).

Comment: This was the conclusion i arrived at as well. The stream.publish option it the best alternative. It is however slightly different than the share function.